# Build Unit Tests to test app going into background

Tags: ios, xcode, unit-testing

Is there a way to build a unit test that can simulate and test what my app should do when it enters the background or is quit?

Thanks...

Comment: Have you tried using [profiler](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html)?

Comment: No, I haven't. I'll take a look. Thnaks!